# Xamarin Forms PanGesture has inconsequent coordinates

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I created an image within a AbsoluteLayout with a panGestureRecognizer, but when I use that to move the image in the app, it jumps back and forth. Very annoying. Here is the code I am using

```
private void AddImageToPreview(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
    {
        var image = (Image)e.NewItems[e.NewItems.Count - 1];

        PanGestureRecognizer panGesture = new PanGestureRecognizer();
        panGesture.PanUpdated += PanUpdated;
        image.GestureRecognizers.Add(panGesture);

        MyLayout.Children.Add(image);
    }
}

void PanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs args)
{
    Image image = (Image)sender;

    if (args.StatusType.Equals(GestureStatus.Running))
    {
        x = args.TotalX;
        y = args.TotalY;

        image.TranslateTo(x, y, 1);
    }
}
```

Can someone help me improve this, so this drag/drop system works smooth and fast!

Comment: Are you trying to create an image that can zoom in and out?

Comment: At the end I want to do that, but first I want to be able to move the image. But when I move the image now, it just keeps jumping back and forth!

Comment: I have a ready-made View that you could use if you are interested, its purely in Xamarin Forms

Comment: Okay, but its just weird why it jumps arround. I have seen lots of examples, but maybe it is different in the way how I create everything?

Comment: Why don't you use skia sharp, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/transforms/touch It's effective and achievable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a control purely made in Xamarin.Forms that you can use for the above mentioned usage:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using FFImageLoading.Forms;

 public class ZoomImage : CachedImage
{
    private const double MIN_SCALE = 1;
    private const double MAX_SCALE = 4;
    private const double OVERSHOOT = 0.15;
    private double StartScale, LastScale;
    private double StartX, StartY;

    public ZoomImage()
    {
        var pinch = new PinchGestureRecognizer();
        pinch.PinchUpdated += OnPinchUpdated;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(pinch);

        var pan = new PanGestureRecognizer();
        pan.PanUpdated += OnPanUpdated;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(pan);

        var tap = new TapGestureRecognizer { NumberOfTapsRequired = 2 };
        tap.Tapped += OnTapped;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(tap);

        Scale = MIN_SCALE;
        TranslationX = TranslationY = 0;
        AnchorX = AnchorY = 0;
    }

    protected override SizeRequest OnMeasure(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
    {
        Scale = MIN_SCALE;
        TranslationX = TranslationY = 0;
        AnchorX = AnchorY = 0;
        return base.OnMeasure(widthConstraint, heightConstraint);
    }

    private void OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Scale > MIN_SCALE)
        {
            this.ScaleTo(MIN_SCALE, 250, Easing.CubicInOut);
            this.TranslateTo(0, 0, 250, Easing.CubicInOut);
        }
        else
        {
            AnchorX = AnchorY = 0.5; //TODO tapped position
            this.ScaleTo(MAX_SCALE, 250, Easing.CubicInOut);
        }
    }

    private void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.StatusType)
        {
            case GestureStatus.Started:
                StartX = (1 - AnchorX) * Width;
                StartY = (1 - AnchorY) * Height;
                break;
            case GestureStatus.Running:
                AnchorX = Clamp(1 - (StartX + e.TotalX) / Width, 0, 1);
                AnchorY = Clamp(1 - (StartY + e.TotalY) / Height, 0, 1);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void OnPinchUpdated(object sender, PinchGestureUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Status)
        {
            case GestureStatus.Started:
                LastScale = e.Scale;
                StartScale = Scale;
                AnchorX = e.ScaleOrigin.X;
                AnchorY = e.ScaleOrigin.Y;
                break;
            case GestureStatus.Running:
                if (e.Scale < 0 || Math.Abs(LastScale - e.Scale) > (LastScale * 1.3) - LastScale)
                { return; }
                LastScale = e.Scale;
                var current = Scale + (e.Scale - 1) * StartScale;
                Scale = Clamp(current, MIN_SCALE * (1 - OVERSHOOT), MAX_SCALE * (1 + OVERSHOOT));
                break;
            case GestureStatus.Completed:
                if (Scale > MAX_SCALE)
                    this.ScaleTo(MAX_SCALE, 250, Easing.SpringOut);
                else if (Scale < MIN_SCALE)
                    this.ScaleTo(MIN_SCALE, 250, Easing.SpringOut);
                break;
        }
    }

    private T Clamp<T>(T value, T minimum, T maximum) where T: IComparable
    {
        if (value.CompareTo(minimum) < 0)
            return minimum;
        else if (value.CompareTo(maximum) > 0)
            return maximum;
        else
            return value;
    }
}
```

What this does:

**Pinch zoom, Pan and Swipe movements together with double tap centre zoom and un-zoom**

Note: I have used FFimageLoading's `CachedImage` because I needed to cache the data in case you do not intend this replace `CachedImage` with `Xamarin.Forms.Image`

Comment: Still jumping back and forth!?

Comment: Can you try to simulate my situation. I am adding an image from a Collection to a AbsoluteLayout with a PanGestureRecognizer

Comment: If you are using my code why do you still need a pangesture, it's already there in the ZoomImage